# Change HTML with CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, line, stylesheet

A site I visit for videogame news decided to drop descriptions from article links. I'm creating a custom stylesheet to add them back. The new style is far too bland and generic for my taste.

OLD VERSION

```
WING COMMANDER: PRIVATEER
Does the spinoff sink or swim?
```

NEW VERSION

```
REVIEW - WING COMMANDER: PRIVATEER
```

If you click on the link it retains the description as as the article's sub-heading. Is there a CSS command to display text from a link?

---

Here is the HTML

```
<a href="www.vidgamer.com/articles/2018/01/20/wing-commander-privateer"> 
  <h3 class="item-title"> 
    Does the spinoff sink or swim?                     
  </h3>
</a>
```

Is linking to text on another page possible?

```
.item-title:after
{
content: url(view-source:www.vidgamer.com/articles/2018/01/20/wing-commander-privateer#536)
}
```

The sub heading is always on line #536 on the page's html.

Comment: This is best done with JS. You can request the other page and then scrape it for whatever text you need.

Comment: Yes, there are special add-ons to do that, such as GreaseMonkey. But if you want it in CSS only, it depends. In your example HTML, it may get hidden with `display:none`, then you'll have to put `display:block` in your custom sheet to get it back. Or they may be using `font-size:0`, then you need `font-size:1rem`. Or they have `position:absolute; right:100%` or `text-indent:-1000em` or `height:0; overflow:hidden` or `opacity:0` etc. You get the idea.